# Removing all commits from a git repository containing only deleted files

Tags: git

One of our huge repos has grown organically to contain two projects over the years. The projects have now diverged so much that we decided that we'd rather have them in separate repositories.

Splitting them up is no problem (duplicate repo, delete project A in repo 1 and delete project B in repo 2), nor is moving the projects to the repo root instead of repo/projectX (`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`).

However, we have over 8000 commits, and the vast majority of them only touch one of the projects, not both. Ideally, we would like to purge commits towards project A from repo2, and vice versa.

Is there a script or a tool to do that kind of thing ? Logically it seems simple:

```
for each commit {
  if all files startwith '/projectA' delete commit
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a tangled mess to me.  How would you know that deleting one commit in project A might not have some downstream effect on project B?  Also, rewriting history in this way by deleting commits entirely could be a real nightmare to implement.  I vote against doing this.

Comment: do this projects persist is separate directories? If they do than you can split repo by directories. https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Comment: I recommend abandoning that rotten timeline and starting two new ones, then you'll have the old 'legacy repo' for the ancient commits, which you will rarely need. Tinkering with the timeline will always have consequences, avoid them by starting over :)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to *change* anything about *any* commit.

At the same time, each commit records the hash ID (directly: the raw hash ID) of its predecessor (*parent*) commit.

When you put these two facts together, what you find is that it's impossible to delete a commit out of the middle of a chain.  Here's a simple toy example, with just three commits in the entire repository:

```
A <--B <--C   <--master
```

Here, the name `master` holds the ID of the third commit `C`.  This is the final commit: that's where Git starts work.  From commit `C`, Git reads the hash ID of the *second* commit `B`.  From commit `B`, Git reads the hash ID of the *first* commit `A`.  Commit `A` has *no* parent, so the action stops, and we have just seen the history.

You now decide you want to remove commit `B`.  Commit `C` *cannot be changed*, but there *is* something you can do: you can *extract* commit `C`, make some changes, and *re-commit the result* to make a new commit that we could call `D`, but let's call it `C'` instead:

```
A--B--C
 \
  C'
```

The change we want to make before we make `C'` is to eliminate two things:

- The *effect of commit `B` on the source tree:* Whatever changed in `B`, we put back, somehow.
- The *parent* of new commit `C'` should be `A`, not `B`.

When we have finished this process, we have a new history in which commit `B` never appears.  However, the name `master` must now point to a new, different commit `C'`:

```
  B--C   [abandoned]
 /
A--C'  <-- master
```

If we had a larger repository with more commits, and wanted to skip, say, two of them, the process would be very similar:

```
  B--C--D--E--F--G--H   [abandoned]
 /
A--C'-F'-G'-H'   <-- master
```

Note that the abandoned commits *remain in the repository for some period of time* but are eventually thrown out via Git's "garbage collection" process (`git gc`), *provided* you make sure you never re-connect to the old commits by, e.g., merging commit `H` with commit `H'`.

Any existing clones that still have `master` pointing to `H` must be treated as radioactive, lest you accidentally merge `H` into `H'` and bring all those commits back.

#### Git filter-branch

Git comes with a tool that allows you to do just the kind of thing described above.  This tool is, however, something like a Swiss Army Chainsaw with no guards against chopping off hands, feet, heads, and so forth.  It is not particularly easy to use, especially for the task you have set yourself here.

What it does is simply enumerate *reachable commits* in the repository (see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) and read up on Git's usage of graph theory).  Then it runs a loop that:

- extracts each commit into a temporary area
- allows you to perform arbitrary work on the extracted commit
- re-commits the result, or (via `--commit-filter`) allows you to *skip* committing the result

and along the way keeps a map of "original hash ID ⟶ new hash ID" for mapping parent hash IDs.  You'll want to understand how "remap to ancestor" works when skipping commits like this.

Re-copying every commit in a repository is slow.  In some cases, such as when using `--tree-filter` which literally extracts every commit, it's excruciatingly slow.  As a result, filter-branch has many filter options to try to speed things up.  Remember that these options are essentially just optimization tricks: as someone intending to use filter-branch as a tool, you should start by defining the problem clearly and coming up with the correct solution (i.e., how to modify the source tree snapshot and the commits) and only then see if you can use an optimized path (such as `--index-filter`) for the snapshot editing.

If you have tags in your repository, remember that filter-branch won't rewrite the tags to point to the new commit hashes unless you supply a `--tag-name-filter`.

Finally, remember, if you choose to go this path—even if you use a tool you write yourself instead of using `git filter-branch`—what you are doing is making *copies* of some subset of the original commits.  The new repository is no longer compatible with *any* existing clone of the old one!